# Parabolic mirror with a bit calculus

Tags: calculus

Consider a parabolic mirror with equation $$ y = -\frac{1}{4} + x^2 $$ and focus at origin.A ray of light travelling  down vertically along line $x=a$ hits mirror at point $(a, b)$  where $$b = -\frac{1}{4} + a^2$$ and goes to origin along a ray at angle  $\theta$ measured from positive x axis. Find formula for $\tan(\theta)$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ and calculate $\frac{d\theta}{da}$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

This line from $(a,b)$ that reflects from the mirror equation passes through the focus, which is the origin in this case. Thus we have the following, in terms of a single variable $a$:
$$(a,b)\equiv (a,-\frac14+a^2)$$
A line that passes through this and the origin:
$$y=\big(-\frac1{4a}+a\big)x$$
The angle between this line and the $x$-axis is given by:

> $$\theta=\arctan(a/b)\;\;\;\;\;\text{for some line:}\;\;ax+by+c=0$$

Thus,
$$\theta=\arctan(\frac1{4a}-a)$$
$$\color{blue}{\tan\theta=\frac1{4a}-a=-\frac{b}{a}}$$
And calculating the derivative w.r.t $a$ as requested by OP:
$$\frac{d\theta}{da}\sec^2\theta=-\frac1{4a^2}-1$$
$$\therefore\color{blue}{\frac{d\theta}{da}=-\frac{\cos^2\theta}{4a^2}-\cos^2\theta}$$

Comment: You should avoid answering poor quality questions. You are just doing this person's work for them.